# Can values be evicted from ObjectCache even if InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration is used?

Tags: c#, caching

I'd like to cache certain values forever and would like to be sure, they're there when I access them.

Currently I use the following code:

```
ObjectCache objectCache = MemoryCache.Default;
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration };

objectCache.Set(new CacheItem("anykey", anyobject), policy);
```

In the documentation on MSDN the following is written about the setting ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration:

> However, a cache entry with this setting can be evicted from the cache
>   for other reasons that are determined by a particular cache
>   implementation, such as a change-monitor event eviction caused by
>   memory pressure.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.infiniteabsoluteexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx

Does it mean, any cache-values will be purged, if my windows-service would crash with an OutOfMemoryException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, cache values can be evicted or purged even if you use InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration.

If your program can't handle missing cache values (which it probably should), then you need to handle the case where an item is removed for eviction regardless of OutOfMemoryExceptions. MemoryCache (as part of ObjectCache) has an UpdateCallback delegate that can be set like this:

```
private void PopulateCache(Widget value)
{
    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    policy.UpdateCallback = CacheUpdate;
    _cache.Set(GetCacheItemKey(value), value, policy);
}

private void CacheUpdate(CacheEntryUpdateArguments args)
{
    // if expired or evicted, put it back in!
    if (args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired || args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Evicted)
    {
        _cache.Set(args.Key, _cache[args.Key], CacheItemPolicy);
    }
    // if removed or ChangeMonitorChanged, do nothing
}
```

For more information check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988702(v=vs.110).aspx

As a best practice, the typical pattern, however, is that when you go to retrieve a value from cache, if the item is expired/evicted, you should get the item from your data store and repopulate the cache.

Answer (score 0):

While Finster answer is correct, I will make an addition to it if you are using default instance of MemoryCache (MemoryCache.Default).

Somehow, simple `Set` method doesn't add new CacheItem to default instance in UpdateCallback (or at least it's not available in subsequent reads from cache).

Basically, you need to set new CacheItem directly on UpdatedCacheItem function argument object and that solves the problem.

```
private void CacheUpdate(CacheEntryUpdateArguments args)
{
    // if expired or evicted, put it back in!
    if (args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired || args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Evicted)
    {
       args.UpdatedCacheItem = new CacheItem(args.Key, "value");
       args.UpdatedCacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    }
}
```

Credits:
http://pdalinis.blogspot.com/2013/06/auto-refresh-caching-for-net-using.html